# Awk: merging columns from files

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, awk, text-parsing

I have two files, and I have to take columns I need from both files and merge them together. I'd like to use awk to do this.

So from FileB I need $9->$12. If $4 of FileA matches what is in $12 of FileB, I'd need $1,$2,$3,$5, and $6 from FileA.

Here's what I have so far:

script.awk:

```
FNR==NR {
    blah = $12
    gsub(/"/,"",blah); gsub(/;/,"",blah);
    array[blah]=$9,$10,$11,$12  ## This breaks here
    next
}

{
    if ($4 in array) {
        print $1,"TransMap","Tcon",$2,$3,$5,$6,".",array[$4]
    }
}
```

I'd run this like: awk -f script.awk fileB fileA
So notice that $12 of FileB isn't an exact match -- any matches with $4 would be in this format: "$4"; (hence the gsubs). I need that format as opposed to what's in $4 in the final output, that's why I did it this way.

The array[blah]=$9,$10... line breaks awk (obviously). But I need all 4 of those fields from FileB -- how would I fix that? Online instructions for awk wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 array[blah]=$9","$10","$11","$12
```

i can only **guess** the problem without seeing the data. I guess you want to get $9-12 concatenated by comma.